# Are C++ meta-templates required knowledge for programmers?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

In my experience Meta-templates are really fun (when your compilers are compliant), and can give good performance boosts, and luckily I'm surrounded by seasoned C++ programmers that also grok meta-templates, however occasionally a new developer arrives and can't make heads or tails of some of the meta-template tricks we use (mostly Andrei Alenxandrescu stuff), for a few weeks until he gets initiated appropriately.

So I was wondering what's the situation for other C++ programmers out there?
Should meta-template programming be something C++ programmers should be "required" to know (excluding entry level students of course), or not?

Edit: Note my question is related to production code and not little samples or prototypes

Comment: is that me, or the title of the question really is different from the question asked?

Comment: Now that you mention it, you are right, the question doesn't match. So I changed it to match better the content of the question

Comment: What's a "meta template"? Don't you mean template meta-programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can you find enough candidates who really know template meta-programing then by all means, require it.  You will be showing a lot of qualified and potentially productive people the door (there are plenty of legitimate reasons not to know how to do this, namely that if you do it on a lot of platforms, you will create code that can't compile, or that average developers will have trouble understanding).  Template meta-programming is great, but let's face it, it's pushing C++ to the limit.
   Now, a candidate should probably understand basics (compute n! at compile time, or at least explain how it works if they are shown the code).  If your new developers are reliably becoming productive within a few weeks, then your current recruiting is probably pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but I would not personally place a high priority on it. It's a nifty feature, but it's a bit situational, and good C++ code can be developed without it. I've personally used it once or twice, but haven't really found it to be valuable enough in *my* work to regularly use it.  (Maybe that's a function of my lack of C++ production experience, though)

Answer (score 3):

The only use I've ever made of template metaprogramming in production code is to unroll a critical loop which read a hardware register N times, followed by another M times, N, M different for different hardware and known at compile time.  In general, the techniques don't seem a natural fit for our codebase, and I'd never get them through a code review.

Answer (score 2):

Required?  As always, it depends.  For those of us in embedded land who are just now getting semi-decent C++ compilers for our tiny little DSPs and what not, we're just happy to be able to use classes.

However, if you've got a halfway decent C++ compiler, say gcc 3.3ish+, then yes, you should look at template metaprogramming.  A good start is the boost library, of course, because it covers most of the templates you seem to look around for when the STL runs out of gas.  It also serves as a great jumping off point.

However, sometimes I find that the advantages of template metaprogramming (lots of nice type safe code with a few lines of < and >) aren't worth the cost that it's going to take.  Sometimes, a good old for( container::const_iterator iter = ... ) does what you need just fine.

Answer (score 2):

18 months later and this topic is still very relevent.  I would still say that template meta programming is not required knowledge, but you need to be able to at least read and explain the basics such as conditionals and the curiously repeating template pattern (looping).  Beyond that, as long as you have a few people who can write a good interface to it, then just basic to intermediate template knowledge is all that is really required, though YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who makes reasonable (although not extensive) use of templates and meta-programming, I go out of my way to try to make the interfaces (and by that I mean the internal usage interfaces) as normal as possible. Not everyone can understand templates, and even those that can sometimes cannot understand complex or obtuse meta programming paradigms.

With that said, if you want to dig in a modify my low-level libraries, you're going to have to know quite a bit. However, you should not even have to know templates (aside from baseline knowledge) to use them. That's how I draw the line at least, and the knowledge level I would expect in other developers (depending on how they are using the code).

Comment: Yes this describes more or less the way we do it to. We wrap up our code in friendly end-user APIs with no < >'s, but our core developers need to understand what's going on behind that

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider template programming required, but it's definitely good to know. You should know enough about the subject to be able to effectively use template libraries such as the STL or Boost.

When I interview someone, I will always ask some questions about template meta-programming. If the candidate doesn't know about the subject, I would never hold that against them. But if they do, then it's a big plus in their favor.

Answer (score -1):

It's not absolutely necessary to know how to use C++ templates.  You can do most things without them.  They are however a fantastic feature.

Since you roll your own templates, anyone new is going to have to come up to speed with them just like the rest of your code which is going to be the bigger chunk of the learning.

I encourage people to learn to use some of the features of the **STL**.  I have used this library in production code and it does save time and simplify things quite a bit.  I also roll my own when the need arises.

I've also heard good things about the **boost** library.

If I need to write portable code then I'll generally stick away from templates because many compilers still don't support them properly.  If you need a portable STL then **STLPort** is the most portable.

Comment: I suspect the reason this was down-voted is that good C++ code all but requires the STL, and often various Boost libraries too. Templates are non-optional when using those, and any modern compiler (even Visual C++, after v6.0) fully supports them -- STLPort is not required.

Comment: Do I smell a Peer Pressure badge?